# Are the Wronskian and the Jacobian related?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, jacobian

The Jacobian can be seen as a 'derivative' of a vector field. The Wronskian is a determinant of a matrix that is filled with higher derivatives along the column and is used to test linear independence of solutions to differential equations.

They must be related in some way, is there a way to connect them in a simple equation?

Comment: See Abel's identity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity